# Can someone identify these two Bell helicopters seen in the Czech Republic?

Tags: helicopter, aircraft-identification

I would like to ask you for help with identification of two particular airframes.

On Sunday 13 May 2018 around 11.45 local time, I took a picture of two Bell UH-1s south of Brno, Czech Republic. I had only wide lens, so it is not very detailed shot. From what I can see, the heli on the left is very likely Bell 212 (or UH-1N), wearing some colorful paint, maybe in SAR version (it probably has also some sensor ball under nose, or reflector), the heli on the right appears to be Bell 214 wearing military camo or dark paint (green or brown), also with sensor ball. They were flying from east to west, approximately in direction from Slovakia to Germany.

Is anybody here able to help me with as precise identification of these two helicopters as possible: version, operator, tail number...?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The mystery has been solved.
Those two helicopters are Agusta-Bell AB 212 operated by Italian Air Force (Aeronautica Militare) coming for Tiger Meet in Poznan, Poland. Their flight route was a little bit confusing because they were VFR flight avoiding CTR.
The more colorful one wears new special tiger paint: https://www.planespotters.net/photo/836257/mm81151-aeronautica-militare-italian-air-force-agusta-bell-ab-212 
The second one seems to wear standard camo: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-czFFf-7KQyA/Wvu5eNjjgXI/AAAAAAAAMQs/qN9qakgSI9QTmqfosho3Dr6DVmHl-nTNwCLcBGAs/s1600/NTM05.jpg 
Thank you, Walker, for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Your assessment seems reasonable. Left HAS a stabilizer bar, so probably 212 / UH1N. Right almost looks to have a stabilizer bar which would rule out 214 variants. If it in fact has a stabilizer bar, the modernized 205 now called 210 with the sharper nose would be my guess.